# proper way to send PublicKey from objectStreams in sockets?

Tags: java, sockets, encryption

I am using the RSA algorithm to to encrypt/decrypt messages between client and server but before i can do that i need to exchange their public keys since i want each of them to have their own pair, after the exchange i encrypt with the opposite publick key and send the message. My problem lies when i exchange the keys. Here is my exchange part:

Server:

```
ObjectOutputStream obOut = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
ObjectInputStream obIn = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

obOut.writeObject(publicKey);
obOut.flush();
Object obj = obIn.readObject();
otherPublicKey = (PublicKey) obj;
```

Client:

```
ObjectOutputStream obOut = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
ObjectInputStream obIn = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

obOut.writeObject(publicKey);
obOut.flush();
Object obj = obIn.readObject();
otherPublicKey = (PublicKey) obj;
```

Exception:

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Data must start with zero

at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:325)
at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:272)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:356)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:382)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2086)
```

I understand that probably my mistake is when i cast the object to PublicKey. So my question is what is a more proper way to do this.

**EDIT:**

forgot to mention that i use this RSA algorithm for encryption/decryption:

```
public static String encryptWithPublicKey(byte[] message, PublicKey publicKey) throws Exception {
    PublicKey apiPublicKey = publicKey;
    Cipher rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    rsaCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, apiPublicKey);
    byte[] encVal = rsaCipher.doFinal(message);
    String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
    return encryptedValue;
}

public static String decryptWithPrivateKey(byte[] message, PrivateKey privateKey) throws Exception {
    PrivateKey pKey = privateKey;
    Cipher rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    rsaCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pKey);
    byte[] decVal = rsaCipher.doFinal(message);
    String decryptedValue = new String(decVal);
    return decryptedValue;
}
```

Comment: Just wanna put out there, the problem probably isn't casting. I use `Object*Streams`, which I use different classes to sort things out. Casting shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: well i tried a few things after that. the thing is i want to use the streams for constant communication, basically i am building a chat. and i've read that objectoutput goes first from objectinput but there is a part in my code that i only need the input and it gets stuck there and now i get no results

Comment: I hope this is just a practice exercise and that you don't deploy this broken protocol anywhere. It's not secure against man-in-the-middle attacks, replays, chosen ciphertext attacks, etc. Just use TLS.

Comment: XY problem. You've provided zero evidence that the problem is in the key exchange. Serialization doesn't corrupt data. The problem is in your encryption code, or your decryption code, or your unseen (or possibly missing) base64 decoding, ... NB as the original message was a byte[], your decrypt method should return a byte[], not a String. Keep it symmetrical. byte[] could be binary, and String is not a container for binary data.

Answer (score 1):

If this is all the relevant code, you're base64-encoding, but you aren't base64-decoding.

Answer (score -1):

I would change it around so it looks like this see if this helps

Client:

```
ObjectOutputStream obOut = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
ObjectInputStream obIn = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

obOut.writeObject(publicKey);
obOut.flush();
Object obj = obIn.readObject();
otherPublicKey = (PublicKey) obj;
```

Server:

```
ObjectOutputStream obOut = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
ObjectInputStream obIn = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

Object obj = obIn.readObject();
otherPublicKey = (PublicKey)obj;
obOut.writeObject(publicKey);
obOut.flush();
```

Comment: no i do get the key back my problem is that i cannot use it because i think i lose precision somewhere. later i use it for encryption decryption and now my inputstream just stays there reading endlessly

Comment: @Παναγιώτης Νικολαρόπουλος Define 'lose precision somewhere'. Are you suggesting that Serialization mysteriously loses data? Why?How? Where's your evidence?

Comment: @3kings *Why* are you suggesting this? What problem is it intended to solve?